# While sempre retorna o último registro em sql server

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server

Tenho um select para trazer todos os registros que foram inseridos e preciso fazer um while para percorrer este select e dar um insert em outra tabela temporária. Só que o while está trazendo sempre o último registro

O que pode estar errado?

```
        DECLARE @CONTADOR INT 
        DECLARE @CONTADORLOOP INT = 1

        SELECT @CONTADOR = COUNT(*) FROM #tableConta

        SELECT * FROM #tableConta

        WHILE(@CONTADORLOOP IS NOT NULL AND @CONTADORLOOP <= @CONTADOR)
        BEGIN

            SELECT @EMP_VLR = EMPCOD, @PLANO_COD_RED = PLANOCODRED FROM #tableConta where PLANOCODRED = @P_PLANO_CTA_COD_RED

            PRINT @EMP_VLR
            --INSERT INTO #tableDebCred (TOTAL2, EMPCOD2, PLANOCODRED) VALUES (@VLRTOTAL2, @EMP_VLR, @PLANO_COD_RED)

                SET @CONTADORLOOP = @CONTADORLOOP  + 1 

        END

    END
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: O que há em `@P_PLANO_CTA_COD_RED` ?

Comment: ela pega o valor declarado em uma variável ali foi 18906 como pode ver na imagem

Comment: dentro do seu while você recupera todos os registros de `#tableConta` já que seu `PLANOCODRED` é o mesmo para todas as linhas. É isto mesmo que deseja fazer ? E mais, o `Insert into` com `select` não te atende neste caso ?

Comment: como que ficaria dai? Tem algum exemplo?

Comment: Veja se atende. [Exemplo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25969/insert-into-values-select-from)

Answer (score 1):

Se eu entendi direito acredito que um `Insert` com `Select` atenderia sua necessidade

```
INSERT INTO TABLEDEBCRED (TOTAL2, EMPCOD2, PLANOCODRED)
SELECT @TOTAL2, EMPCOD, PLANOCODRED FROM TABLECONTA
    WHERE PLANOCODRED = @P_PLANO_CTA_COD_RED;
```